# Access to fetch from api blocked by CORS policy: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a route on React where I change the user password.

```
const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const userId = useParams().userId;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [formState, inputHandler] = useForm(
    {
      currentPassword: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false,
      },
      newPassword: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false,
      },
      confirmNewPassword: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false,
      },
    },
    false
  );

  const changePasswordHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      formState.inputs.newPassword.value ===
      formState.inputs.confirmNewPassword.value
    ) {
      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("password", formState.inputs.confirmNewPassword.value);
        await sendRequest(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL +
            `/users/${userId}/change-password`,
          "PATCH",
          formData,
          {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        );
        navigate(`/users/${userId}`);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="changePasswordForm">
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
      <Card className="changePassword">
        {!isLoading && inputHandler && (
          <form onSubmit={changePasswordHandler}>
            <Input
              element="input"
              id="currentPassword"
              type="password"
              label="Current Password"
              validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
              onInput={inputHandler}
            />
            <Input
              element="input"
              id="newPassword"
              type="password"
              label="New Password"
              validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
              onInput={inputHandler}
            />
            <Input
              element="input"
              id="confirmNewPassword"
              type="password"
              label="Confirm New Password"
              validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
              onInput={inputHandler}
            />
            <Button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isValid}>
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Card>
    </div>
```

Every other route is working nice, even another route which is similar to the one I'm facing problems. It's a route to update user info and it works great. I have tried to add the mode: 'no-cors' but it still didn't work. The headers on backend are okay as other routes work great.

It works great on postman too so it's not a backend problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not in the front-end code. The solution is adding headers to your back-end for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. If you are using NodeJS, set the headers like this as a middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  next()
})
```

Comment: I do have the headers though.